# Code Igniter Custom Helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am new to Code igniter / OOP but trying to figure this out.

I am trying to make a helper that I can use in my code; this is what it looks like:

```
if ( ! function_exists('email'))
{
    function email($type, $to, $subject, $object)
    {
        switch($type){

            case 'new':

                $body = "Hello ". $object['FirstName'] . ' ' . $object['LastName'] . ","
                    . "<p/><p/>Thank you.";
                break;
        }

        // Send it
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->from('blah@website.com', 'James');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($body);
        $this->email->send();

    }
}
```

I then include it in the autoload for the helper section.

When i try to access it within my controller, I get an error.

```
$obect['FirstName']='Carl';
$obect['LastName']='Blah';
email('new', 'test@website.com', 'test', $object);
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\attrition\application\helpers\email_helper.php on line 17
```

Comment: try $object->FirstName, and make sure to use a "j" when spelling "object"

Comment: Basically, it comes down to this: the `$this` keyword only makes sense if you're executing code in the method of an instantiated class - otherwise, there is no `$this` to refer to. I recognize that this answer is probably insufficient to help you solve your problem - a full explanation would take much longer. You're going to need to do some more research on object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using **$this** when not in object context

This simply means you can not use the **$this** keyword outside of an object(class), 
as @Kryten pointed out.

Helpers are generally only used for embedding in html, such as formatting data.

```
<p><?php echo formatHelper(escape($var)); ?></p>
```

What you need to do is read up a little on creating a [Library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Answer (score 1):

you'll use that variable instead of $this

so, your $this is change by this

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

How to use? usualy you use $this like

```
$this->load->other();
// change to
$CI->load->other();
```

It should be work

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this code :

```
if ( ! function_exists('email'))
{
    function email($type, $to, $subject, $object)
     {
         switch($type){

             case 'new':

                 $body = "Hello ". $object['FirstName'] . ' ' . $object['LastName'] . ","
                     . "<p/><p/>Thank you.";
                 break;
         }

         // Send it
         $this = &get_instance(); // here you need to get instance of codeigniter for use it
         $this->load->library('email');
         $this->email->to($to);
         $this->email->from('blah@website.com', 'James');
         $this->email->subject($subject);
         $this->email->message($body);
         $this->email->send();

     }
 }
```